# How to Default to the Login Screen if a user is not Logged in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

So I've setup a default route to a specific action, controller and module.
Now when someone goes to the site it will default there.

I have setup authentication and authorisation, and initially it would default to the login action when a user was not logged in.

However that is not the case anymore, and I don't really want to use:

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        if !($auth->hasIdentity())
        {
                     $this->_redirect('/admin/user/login');
                }
```

If there is a more elegant way...

Well I have this elegant solution in a preDispatch method:

```
if (!$acl->isAllowed($role, $controller, $action))
        {
            if ($role == 'guest')
            {
                $request->setControllerName('user');
                $request->setActionName('login');
                $request->setModuleName('admin');
            }
            else
            {
                $request->setControllername('error');
                $request->setActionname('noauth');
            }
        }
```

Seems more elegant but isn't working

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a more elegant way? hasIdentity() is specifically for this use.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to Certain Pages:

```
   return $this->redirect()->toRoute('/admin/user/login');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check is user is allowed to view page must be implemented somewhere else (I preffer X_Controller_Plugin for that operation). The best way I have found for using Acl is to add information to navigation about each page privilege and resource

```
<?php
Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc::factory(
    array(
        'label' => 'home',
        'route' => 'home',
        'privilege' => 'view',
        'resource' => 'guest',
        'pages' => array(...)
    )
);
```

Creating navigation this way forces you to create it in Bootstrap and create pages for dynamically content. For routes such as '/@news/@read/:id' you need to create separate navigation entries. But this creates quite big problem, because best place for creating dynamically content is controller, but you cannot create it in controller because you cannot run code from controller before controller plugin, where you are using navigation for obtaining information about pages privilege and resource.

So you can create controller plugin for each dynamically content (such as news, blog, cms modules) what is not that bad option.

**Pluses of this method:**
You have already navigation tree (which is created dynamically), you have tools for determining privileges for each page, acl check is in one place (not in every controller or worse in every action).

And important thing: Acl check needs to be done in or before preDispatch, after that point action is dispatched without acl check.